# How many shops can each workshop suppily?

Tags: ninja-village

How much output does each workshop produce.  How many shops can I keep stocked with a single workshop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on several factors.

- The primary factor is the Workshop's inherent Production stat.  The higher it is, the faster it is able to produce goods.
- The villager's Work stat also plays a part, in the same way as the building's Production does.
- Distance between the Workshop and Shop.  Obviously, the closer they are, the better it can serve the needs.
- Lastly, the item being produced matters.  If it requires many resources, you'll get less items.  You can mitigate this with multiple workshops.

I've noticed that what Workshops produce is dictated by what the closest shops are.  This seems to be somewhat random, as Workshops will sometimes choose to produce goods of the closest shops, and sometimes, they will choose to produce goods for shops clear across the map!  The best way I've found to mitigate this problem is to build them to a 1:1 ratio.  Build a Workshop, a road, then the shop, all in a line.  In this manner, it seems that the Workshop will only supply the single shop.

Comment: I like your answer better as it explains more